# C# printing with spaces/indent

Tags: c#, printing

Hi I am trying to print a bill/receipt using a receipt printer from C# application.

The intended output is like this:

```
ITEM NAME                 QTY     PRICE
Banana Large Yellow        1       2.00
Brie Cheese 6 pack round   3      30.00
Indian Mango Box          10     246.00
```

The names, quantity and price need to be aligned in a straight line, irrespective of the number of characters in the item name, qty or price.

I have been using `String.Format` function, but the output is often not aligned, and get's spaced depending on the item name length etc.

```
ITEM NAME                 QTY     PRICE
Banana Large Yellow        1       2.00
Brie Cheese 6 pack round     3      30.00
Indian Mango Box        10    246.00
```

How can to fix this?

Code that I have used was

```
test_string = "-------------------------------\r\n";
        test_string += "First Name | Last Name  |   Age\r\n";
        test_string += String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Bill", "Gates", 51) + "\r\n";
        test_string += String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Edna", "Parker", 114) + "\r\n";
        test_string += String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Johnny", "Depp", 44) + "\r\n";
```

I am using following print code

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;      // Horizontal Alignment 

        StringFormat right = new StringFormat();
        right.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far; 

        // Measure string.
        SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
        pd.PrintPage += delegate(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
            {
                string measureString = data;
                Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);


                stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

                RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(0, height_value, pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height);                   
                if (weight == "bold")
                {
                    if (alignment == "center")
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font(font, 11, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), rect, format);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font(font, 11, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), rect);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (alignment == "center")
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font(font, 11), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), rect, format);
                    }
                    else if (alignment == "right")
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font(font, 11), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), rect, right);                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font(font, 11), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), rect);
                    }

                }
                height_value = Convert.ToInt32(stringSize.Height) + height_value;
            };
```

In the above print code I am passing data as

```
public string Test()
    {
        string[] names = { "Banana Large Yellow", "Brie Cheese", "Indian Mango Box" };
        int[] quantities = { 1, 3, 10 };
        decimal[] prices = { 2.00m, 30.00m, 246.00m };

        string format = "{0,-25} {1,-10} {2,5}" + Environment.NewLine;
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().AppendFormat(format, "Item Name", "QTY", "Price");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat(format, names[i], quantities[i], prices[i]);
        }

     PrintFormat(stringBuilder.ToString(), "Arial", "normal", "left", 20);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at String.PadRight

Comment: Does the bill printer use a monospaced font? Have you used field widths in your `String.Format`? See "Controlling formatting" at [Getting started with the String.Format method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Starting).

Comment: Does your code correspond to your example?

Answer (score 4):

Have a closer look at [Alignment component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to increased the first position values, as your strings are longer than 10 chars, give a try with -25.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {

      string[] names = { "Banana Large Yellow", "Brie Cheese", "Indian Mango Box"};
      int[] quantities = { 1,3,10}; 
      decimal[] prices = { 2.00m, 30.00m, 246.00m};

      string format = "{0,-25} {1,-10} {2,10}" + Environment.NewLine;
      var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().AppendFormat(format, "Item Name", "QTY", "Price");
      for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
      {
          stringBuilder.AppendFormat(format, names[i], quantities[i], prices[i]);
      }

      Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());

   }
}

Item Name                 QTY             Price
Banana Large Yellow       1                2.00
Brie Cheese               3               30.00
Indian Mango Box          10             246.00
```

Also do not use string concatenation if you are looping on collection, use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would advise to use directly [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have used the code that you have suggested but I did not get the Hours values with proper alignment in print out.I am concatenating string instead of Consol.WriteLine and out side the for loop I am passing it to printer .

Answer (score 3):

In order to print data in table-like structure you can use `string.Format` using format item with width and alignment.

Let's have a look how it works:

```
// in comments underscores mean spaces
Console.WriteLine("Res:{0,6}.", 12345); //   Res:_12345.
Console.WriteLine("Res:{0,-6}.", 12345); //  Res:12345_.
```

But what if the resulting string length is longer than the specified width? Then the result will be printed as if there was no alignment and width at all.

```
Console.WriteLine("Res:{0,-6}", 123456789); //  Res:123456789.
Console.WriteLine("Res:{0,6}.", 123456789); //  Res:123456789.
```

So in order to solve your problem first define the maximum length of the resulting strings in each of your column and use this value as a width.

> I have used the code that you have suggested but I did not get the Hours values with proper alignment in print out.I am concatenating string instead of Consol.WriteLine and out side the for loop I am passing it to printer

You should better use `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`. It works with format items just like `String.Format` or `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.PadRight(int)`. Refer to my code below, I used `List` to store the elements but it should work the same for array.

Pay attention to `padValue1,2 and 3`, obtain the **padding value for each column** dynamically by matching the length of longest word. I added `2` extra spaces after that.

Then before you print out the string, add `.PadRight(padValue)`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string itemNameTitle = "ITEM NAME";
    string qtyTitle = "QTY";
    string priceTitle = "PRICE";

    List<string> itemName = new List<string> { "Banana Large Yellow", "Brie Cheese 6 pack round", "Indian Mango Box"};
    List<string> qty = new List<string> { "1", "3", "10" };
    List<string> price = new List<string> { "2.00", "30.00", "246.00" };

    //Insert titles into first positions of Lists
    itemName.Insert(0, itemNameTitle);
    qty.Insert(0, qtyTitle);
    price.Insert(0, priceTitle);

    //Dynamically get number of spaces according to longest word length + 2
    int padValue1 = itemName.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length + 2;
    int padValue2 = qty.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length + 2;
    int padValue3 = price.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length + 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemName.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(itemName[i].PadRight(padValue1));
        Console.Write(qty[i].PadRight(padValue2));
        Console.Write(price[i]);
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working on print, (It does work on console however)[link]https://drive.google.com/a/acharis.com/file/d/0B5CAmb2RPmnOdTdVSEVKMUI3aUk/view?usp=sharing
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5CAmb2RPmnOeFU4enNwcFdHSXM